# Does the performance improvement from SVF2 apply to IE?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I verified the difference between SVF and SVF2 with a 1.6GB IFC model.
As a result, "Total geometry size" & "Net GPU geom meometry" has been reduced to about 20%.
But when I view it in IE, the browser crashes.
Does the performance improvement from SVF2 apply to IE?

SVF

[image]

SVF2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimizations are on the file format side, and as such should be not affected by the specific browser.

With that said, however, IE is notoriously known for having all kinds of compatibility issues. The SVF2 file format for example relies on [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) to stream the geometry data to the client, and it's possible that IE could have some problems with that.

While Internet Explorer 11 is listed as a [supported browser](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/#browser-requirements), I would recommend using any of the modern browsers instead if possible. And if you do need to use IE11, please send a bug report to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, including details about your OS and browser, and any error logs you see in the browser console.